# Minimal .apks for play store

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, installation, apk

## Introduction

I just installed CyanogenMod 10.2 on HTC One X+ and I want to install ONLY the Google Play Store. I know there is Gapps, but I want to have even less apps on my phone than what is in that package. I searched already for a long time on the internet, but couldn't find a clear solution. I hope you can help me :)
(I know about F-Droid, also have that on my phone, but I wish to have Play Store too)

## What I did so far:

- I downloaded Play Store (cm.android.vending-4.6.16.apk) from Android Police: http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/13/download-latest-google-play-store-4-6-16-with-new-require-password-option-tweaked-ui-forced-self-update-and-more/
- Got the Gapps zip for CM 10.2: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps
- From Gapps I took the files "GmsCore.apk", "GoogleLoginService.apk" and "GoogleServicesFramework.apk".
- I moved these 3 apks to my phone and relocated these 3 apks to the folder /system/app/
- I installed the Play Store (cm.android.vending-4.6.16.apk)

### Note

If you don't put "GmsCore.apk" on your phone, Google Play Store will start, but you will have no connection in the store.

## The Problem

I can start Play Store and have connection with the store, but the moment I want to install an app or check for updates (settings --> Build version (4.6.16)) it says: "Unfortunately, Google Play Store has stopped." How to solve this?

Comment: Not a clear answer, but you might wish to take a look at [Open Source implementation of Google Play Services](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2184/185#3592). The NOGAPPS packages might prove helpful here :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well... finding an old package, looking at those files I discovered the answer. Sometimes it takes very long to find it and the solution is simple.

## Short Answer

You should also move "Phonesky.apk" to /system/app/ folder and then restart your phone.

## Summary

- Download the latest Play Store .apk (Try for example Android Police): http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/13/download-latest-google-play-store-4-6-16-with-new-require-password-option-tweaked-ui-forced-self-update-and-more/
- Get the Gapps .zip for your system: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps
- From this .zip, move these 4 files to your phone storage: "GmsCore.apk", "GoogleLoginService.apk", "GoogleServicesFramework.apk" and "Phonesky.apk".
- Use a File Explorer (like File Manager with root right) to move these 4 files to /system/app/
- Install Play Store .apk (for example: cm.android.vending-4.6.16.apk)
- Restart phone
- Done :D

### Edit: WARNING 2015-05-16

Even though this works, I now recommended just installing the whole gapps. Just now I tried to update my cyanogenmod to CM 11, which failed, but when trying to set my backup back, all was reset to the state when you just flashed CM (although the data was still there, so smart apps recognize this). This was solved by 1 of the following 2 things:

- First flashing a clean CM 10.2, then restoring my backup with TWRP (if did this the trick, you can ignore this warning)
- Flashing Gapps for CM 10.2: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps

Comment: In my opengapps 6.0 on cm13 all these apks are in `/system/priv-app/`; should I still put them in `/system/app/` if I try your method to get rid of gapps?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე this was on Cyanogenmod 10, which is equivalent of Android 2 or 4? It seems that 6 changed quite a bit, so don't take the folders literally in this answer. I don't even know if this answer even works anymore in Android 6. If you found them in `/system/priv-app/`, then it's more likely to put them back there, but that's pure speculation.