# Play Store crahes after reinstall in /system/app

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat

I've Archos 45B Helium rooted, with 4.4.4 android version. 
I've got some problem with Play Store so I backed up it with Titanium and I delete it. I was not able to restore. So I downloaded "com.android.vending-5.3.5" and I instaled it as Phonesky.apk in the /system/app directory and change is permission to 644.
Now Play Store is installed but it crashes all the times.

Could I take Google_Apps wich are in the http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps
and which version I've to take.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Following  I installed 5.2.13 in place of 5.3.5 version of play store as above. The tool didn't crash but it doesn't to download  any softwares.

Comment: Did you clear Play Store data? It is not recommended to flash gapps packages on stock ROMs but I don't see why shouldn't it work. For KitKat, choose CM11 file.

Comment: Yes, and I wiped the cache that removed my Play Store. Archos web site doesn't give any firmware for this device.  On this question [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69018/minimal-apks-for-play-store) gives clues but I don't know how to apply them and if there's any compatibility problem.

Comment: I've got self signed error when I tried to flash CM11 Gapps on my devices :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android 4.4.4 there is no more /system/app but /system/priv-app the main directory of the applications need special access
Following this [Link of Android exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102080/how-to-know-which-gapps-version-is-installed)
I checke dthe version of the tols was not removed. I my case I did that with the 4.4.22 version of Google play store

```
adb shell
shell@ac45bhe:/ $ su 
root@ac45bhe:/ # mount -o remount,rw /system
root@ac45bhe:/ # cp /storage/sdcard1/com.android.vending-4.4.22-80240022-minAPI8.apk /system/priv-app/Phonesky.apk
root@ac45bhe:/ # chmod 644 /system/priv-app/Phonesky.apk
root@ac45bhe:/ # reboot
```

And I installed com.android.vending-5.3.5-80330500-minAPI9.apk from Android thought the internal file explorer, accepting unknown source when the system asked.