# How to know which Gapps version is installed?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-apps

How to know which Gapps version is installed in official Roms. I've a Archos 45b Helium with Android 4.4.4 installed.

Comment: If they work then they are most likely the 4.4 Gapps, any further app updates will be done via the app store.

Comment: I need to reinstall play store. May be I've to uninstall the package but the structure of the directories seems not the same following the version you use. There is a delete-list.txt in the Gapps package. Is this list handled by any script or I've to remove manually?

Comment: You could (usually) just install the Play Store via APK. Android Police host the latest updates, and I've used them for years. Or you could just reflash the 4.4 gapps package...I feel like there's more to this question though, other than just installing the store?

Comment: Thanks for comment : Play store installed via APK crashes all the times. I tried to flash the 4.4 gapps from version pa_gapps-modular-pico-4.4.4-20141103 to  pa_gapps-modular-pico-4.4.4-20150308-signed.zip all the I've got the same error : failed to verify whole-file signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SDK package of Android, there's a little tools called "aapt" which gives you information about the version:

```
#~:./aapt dump badging GoogleServicesFramework.apk 
package: name='com.google.android.gsf' versionCode='19' versionName='4.4.4-1288895'
sdkVersion:'19'
targetSdkVersion:'19'

#~:/aapt dump badging GoogleLoginService.apk 
package: name='com.google.android.gsf.login' versionCode='19' versionName='4.4.4-1227136'
sdkVersion:'8'
targetSdkVersion:'17'

#~:/aapt dump badging GmsCore.apk 
package: name='com.google.android.gms' versionCode='5089038' versionName='5.0.89 (1307510-038)'
sdkVersion:'9'
targetSdkVersion:'19'
```

I did these commands in a terminal on my linux workstation, after exported the APK files from my /system/priv-app folder was in my phone.